# Network Speeds Don't Add Up

Tags: networking

I know this isn't a network website but I had to think of a fast way to ask this question where knowledgeable people exist.

I have 12 MBps down, 2 MBps up, I have a home server that when I download from it externally I max at 256 KBps.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Unless you're actually getting that kind of throughput, you might want to change the capitalization on the speed measurement (MBps reads as Mega**bytes**, whereas Mbps reads as Mega**bits**).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bandwidth is really 2Mbps (bits per second... that is 256 kilobytes per second)

```
2 * 1024 / 8 = 265
```

Comment: It's sneaky how ISPs measure bandwidth, but this is right on.

Comment: it's not sneaky, it's how it has always been done.

Comment: It's not really sneaky as all.  It's just how we look at numbers.  If you really want to be confused look how hard drive size is measured.  When they write the number on the box the use the `1000` based values but when you look at the disk size in your file manager it's typically based on the `1024` based value.

Comment: @Toast: Networking always (in my experience, at least) uses bits, so I wouldn't say it's really sneaky. It's not like hard drives, where everyone except drive manufacturers measures storage capacity in base 2.

Comment: I say it's sneaky, because most people don't realize the difference.  I called my isp's tech support to explain it to me, and they told me all the speeds were in bytes.  When I tried to clarify, they didn't know what I was talking about.

Comment: Wow that is lame.  I went from FIOS to DSL so I was use to MegaBYTES per second... this sucks... can't wait to move back into an area with FIOS.

Comment: Wow that is lame.  I went from FIOS to DSL so I was use to MegaBYTES per second... this sucks... can't wait to move back into an area with FIOS.

I have Charter, if I wanted their BEST upload speed it would cost $100/month for 640 KB/s... Or I can move where FIOS is offered get their CHEAPEST offering of $50/month and get the same upload speed!  Or get the next best which is $65/month and get 3.6 MBYTES/sec!!

Answer (score 4):

Bandwidths are **always** measured in *bits per second*, and your home connection will be measured like that too, i.e. 2 Mbps (note - small 'b').

File download displays however tend to show in *bytes per second*, since you really care about the number of bytes you're downloading, not the number of bits :)

So your 256 Kilo *bytes* per second of *download speed* is approximately equal to 2 Mega *bits* per second of *bandwidth*.

Comment: that's _very_ unlikely.  12 MBps is roughly 100 Mega _bits_ per second, i.e. ethernet speeds.

Answer (score 0):

You're bandwidth, as an end user, is always bias towards download speed. You have a maximum bandwidth allotted for both up and down, and most users don't care if they have high upload speed.

edit, are you sure it isn't Kb/s? look at the capitalization of the B

Answer (score 0):

Those are advertised and theoretical speeds. Just like "100Mbps" ethernet doesn't give you 100MBps actual transfer rates, the telcos and cablecos use weasle words such as "up to" or "as much as". The hardware and line may be capable of sustaining a 2Mbps connection outgoing from your home, but that doesn't factor in things such as TCP overhead, throttling, network congestion, etc...

256 v.s. 2000 is a bit extreme, but I'd suggest checking if your ISP is throttling per-connection speeds - try two uploads at the same time. If the effective speed on both drops to 128, then you've really only got a 256kbit link. If both sustain 256kbit, then you're being throttled on a per-connection basis.